# Flutter CachedNetworkImageProvider - How to Show local default image on error?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to show a default local image if CachedNetworkImageProvider fails to get the remote image for some reason:

```js
Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 120.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    image: new DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use the [cached network image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) plugin which has an `errorWidget` parameter, the installation steps are explained on the link. This is an example implementation of it :

```
  image: new CachedNetworkImage(
             imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
             placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
             errorWidget: new Image.assets('error.jpg'), // This is what you need
             fit: BoxFit.fill,
             fadeInCurve: Curves.easeIn ,
             fadeInDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
             fadeOutCurve: Curves.easeOut,
             fadeOutDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),

            ),
```

you can notice that it also has other features like `placeholder` and animations ,so you will have more capabilities to tinker with.

Comment: Thank u for your answer my friend. I already tried this, the problem is I want to use it in a container where I can control it's shape (rectangle or circle). And BoxDecoration image does not accept CachedNetworkImage, saying he argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'. It only accepts CachedNetworkImageProvider. Do you know of a way to use CachedNetworkImage in a widget which allows you to control it's shape? As far as I can tell, the plugin itself does not have anything like a border radius property.

Comment: CachedNetworkImageProvider doesn’t have a defference from normal ImageProvider. It provides just meta information of a image and doesn’t provide any optimizations. So if you want to optimize behavior of image, I recommend you to use CachedNetworkImage and Replace parent Container to another widget(eg. ClipRect, ClipOval). I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jaime if you found any solution, please share it, so it can help others.

Comment: I need output of CachedNetworkImage as CachedNetworkImageProvider because Container decorationImage needs CachedNetworkImageProvider type image. Kindly share your experience. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check out my other answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

@Abdullah Khan - I ended up with this:

```js
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: url,
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setAvatar();
    },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.account_circle,
      size: 100.0,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
  ),
  imageBuilder: (context, image) => Hero(
    tag: 'photo',
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Get.toNamed(Routes.FULLPHOTO,
          arguments: {
            'url': url,
            'name': photoTitle,
            'idx': 0
          });
      },
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: image,
        radius: size,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Get.toNamed comes from the GetX package (great for navigation and state management).

Comment: I need output of CachedNetworkImage as CachedNetworkImageProvider because Container decorationImage needs CachedNetworkImageProvider type image. Kindly share your experience. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamlesh, something like this?:

```js
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 8, top: 8, bottom: 8),
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14)),
    // color: Colors.blue.shade200,
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
        ipath,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```